# Why does it throw an error when it tries to unzip the 1.12 version?

Tags: java, file, io, unzip

I am making an installer for an mc mod it has to donwload the zip file of the mod from a server but when my installer(for the mod) tries to unzip the 1.12 version it throws an but it works with all the other versions.(when I unzip it myself on my pc and zip it again and run my installer again it also works with the 1.12 version).
I tried to rename the file because I first thought it maybe couldn't find it because of the dots in the name: modpack_0.1.0.jar

```
public static void unZip(String src, String dest) {

    try (ZipFile file = new ZipFile(src)) {

        FileSystem fileSystem = FileSystems.getDefault();
        // Get file entries
        Enumeration<? extends ZipEntry> entries = file.entries();

        // We will unzip files in this folder
        String uncompressedDirectory = dest;
        Path path = Paths.get(dest);

        if (Files.exists(path)) {

            deleteDirectoryStream(path);
            Files.createDirectory(fileSystem.getPath(uncompressedDirectory));
        }

        else {

            Files.createDirectory(fileSystem.getPath(uncompressedDirectory));

        }

        // Iterate over entries
        while (entries.hasMoreElements()) {

            ZipEntry entry = entries.nextElement();
            // If directory then create a new directory in uncompressed folder

            if (entry.isDirectory()) {

                System.out.println("Creating Directory:" + uncompressedDirectory + entry.getName());
                Files.createDirectories(fileSystem.getPath(uncompressedDirectory + entry.getName()));

            }
            // Else create the file
            else {

                InputStream is = file.getInputStream(entry);
                BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
                String uncompressedFileName = uncompressedDirectory + entry.getName();
                Path uncompressedFilePath = fileSystem.getPath(uncompressedFileName);
                Files.createFile(uncompressedFilePath);
                FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(uncompressedFileName);

                while (bis.available() > 0) {

                    fileOutput.write(bis.read());

                }

                fileOutput.close();
                System.out.println("Written :" + entry.getName());
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    }
}
```

I expected that it would unzip the 1.12 version without any errors just like the other versions but it gave me an error:

```
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /Users/usernamehere/Library/Application Support/minecraft/mods/CraftingDead/bin/modpack.jar
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:86)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:214)
    at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:361)
    at java.nio.file.Files.createFile(Files.java:632)
    at com.craftingdead.installer.Actions.unZip(Actions.java:144)
    at com.craftingdead.installer.Gui.installModAndForge(Gui.java:185)
    at com.craftingdead.installer.Gui.actionPerformed(Gui.java:429)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2238)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2296)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4897)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4534)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4475)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2282)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:760)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:733)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:730)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.craftingdead.installer.Gui.installModAndForge(Gui.java:200)
    at com.craftingdead.installer.Gui.actionPerformed(Gui.java:429)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2238)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2296)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4897)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4534)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4475)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2282)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:760)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:733)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:730)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Does someone know why it could be giving me an error?

Comment: Copy and paste the error as text. Some of us cannot access imgur.

Comment: Looks like something's may be up with the zip file. Possibly a missing file, or a corrupt zip. You should be able to manually unzip and navigate to that directory and see if you can extract it using something like 7zip or winzip.

Comment: Your exception seems unrelated to your code.

Comment: I’m guessing the `bin` directory doesn’t exist.  Try placing `Files.createDirectories(uncompressedFilePath.getParent());` before your Files.createFile call.

Comment: @VGR thanks that worked but it's really slow now.